# mixed effects models with crossed random factors - how to determine correlation between two Y variables

Tags: mixed-model

As described in a previous post ([mixed effects model with crossed random factors - how to determine whether non-linear relationship b/t X and Y](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/376377/mixed-effects-model-with-crossed-random-factors-how-to-determine-whether-non-l)) I have a data structure that requires a mixed effects model - specifically, I have 3 crossed (rather than nested) factors with random intercepts. The number of levels for each of the 3 random factors is:

level 1: 25

level 2: 29

level 3: 58

I have 2 Y (dependent) variables and am interested in whether these are correlated to the point of redundancy (you can use one in place of another). However, I do not think a simple Pearson's correlation coefficient will suffice due to the complicated data structure. Is there a way to test this, even if it is not necessarily perfect? Thank you!

Comment: How many models did you fit? one for one dependent variable, so 2 models?

Comment: Correct. 2 models.

Comment: No way to work on relation between two random variables when they are not in the same model. Try to put them into one model then to check they relation. But it is not easy.

Comment: Please put the output from `summary()` of both models, and the correlation coefficient between both `Y` variables.

Comment: I actually don't use R so not sure what summary() yields, and am still working on the models, can report back. Pearson's correlation coefficient is 0.67.

Comment: Are you using MPlus or STATA by any chance ? One way to proceed would be with a latent variable mixed model approach where your response variable is a latent variable, measured by the 2 Y variables ? These can be fitted in MPlus natively I believe, and in STATA using GLLAMM.

Comment: In your question, you write about correlation, but I'm wondering whether you mean agreement? I.e., do the two outcomes measure the same thing and you want to see if one can replace the other, or you really want to see how correlated they are? In the former case, you can work with an extension of the Bland & Altman method for repeated measurements data. For the latter, you need to more specifically define which correlations you're interested in.

Comment: I am interested in whether they capture the same thing and if one can replace another. I thought that could be evaluated with a correlation coefficient, but from you are saying that isn't correct. I will look into the Bland & Altman work. I will also look at GLLAMM in Stata for a latent variable mixed model Robert. THANK YOU BOTH!!!

Comment: @StasK is an expert in GLLAMM so if he gets this ping he might be able to advise if it  is /*actually*/ possible, as GLLAMM has quite a steep learning curve.

Comment: Can Bland-Altman ONLY be used if you are comparing two measurement techniques, or can it also be used if you don't have that situation but just want to look at agreement between 2 different variables? Does it matter if the two variables are on a different scale?

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant by "measuring the same thing", i.e., that you compare two measurement techniques. But given that you say that are measured on different scales, it seems that they do not measure exactly the same outcome.